# In the DT algorithm, why not search through all possible splits instead of first choosing the feature required for splitting?

Tags: cart, entropy

As far as I understand the Decision Trees (DT - CART), the first step is to choose a feature that maximizes IG (information gain), meaning the entropy in the current node - the entropy after splitting using that variable.

However, I think the **optimal** next split is achievable by using the best split + feature **directly**, instead of choosing first the **best feature** and then the optimal split among that feature

For example, let's say I have a binary classification with 100 examples where the target is equally distributed (entropy 1) and I have 2 categorical features:

**A** with the following values

- A1(25 examples, all have target 0)
- A2 (25 examples, 16 have target 1)
- A3 (25 examples, 17 have target 1)
- A4 (25 examples, 17 have target 1)

=> entropy of A ~= 0.5

**B** with the following values

- B1(50 examples, 5 have target 1)
- B2(50 examples, 5 have target 0)

=> entropy of B ~= 0.3

I'd have a higher information gain from choosing B instead of A as the feature (0.7 > 0.5). However, the best split is clearly A ({A1}, {A2, A3, A4}).

Did I understand the CART algorithm wrong? How does it guarantee to choose the optimal split at each step?